# Using interstitial in Apple TV TVJS

Tags: ios, tvos, apple-tv, tvml, tvjs

I am working on a new video streaming application for the new apple tv.  I am trying to implement ads into a media item.  Apple provides reference for the `interstitial` which is used to determine where and when ads are displayed.  They have very little information there that is helpful for actually implementing another media item into the `interstitial`.  I am hoping someone has come across this and has accomplished this?

```
interstitial = [
{
      { 
        starttime: 463.2,
        duration: 30
      },
      {
        starttime: 1700,
        duration: 15
      },
}
]
```

This object is a property that I than attach to a `MediaItem`.  Which works fine but where do I actually attach another `MediaItem` to the active video?

Apple clearly states:

`An interstitial object defines a point within a MediaItem object where you can insert another media item`

Reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSMediaItem_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instp/MediaItem/interstitials

Any help is much appreciated.

**Sample:**

Setup player and playlist:

```
var player = new Player();  
var playlist = new Playlist();
```

Setup Media Item:

```
var ad = new MediaItem("video", self.prerolls[i][0]);
```

Attach property for interstitial:

```
ad.interstitial = interstitial;
```

Play:

```
 player.present();
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `interstitials` object on `MediaItem` is to display the ad markers on the player progress bar, and to take them into consideration when calculating the video duration.

If you want to display an interstitial video, you'll need to handle stopping the current video (and remembering when), play your interstitial video, and then play the main video again at the same time. You might want to use the [Player event `timeBoundaryDidCross`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSPlayer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instp/Player/timeBoundaryDidCross) to tell you when you should switch to the interstitial.

Otherwise, take a look at various HLS Server Side Ad Insertion platforms, like [Brightcove Once](https://www.brightcove.com/en/once) or [Adobe Primetime](http://www.adobe.com/au/solutions/primetime/ad-insertion.html). They'll give you an HLS stream that has the ads pre-baked into the stream so you don't have to worry about managing when to play it.

Comment: When handling multiple players (or at least multiple media items) like you describe here, is it possible to prevent the brief moment where the player is exited and the previous view is shown before the ad is displayed?